# facebook sdk user friends image not being returned if using image as background in div

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to get the profile image of a user's friend who logged in. The problem is when I use `img src` to display the returned image, it works and the image is displayed, but when I use `div background-image` then it doesn't return the correct image link.

```
function displayUsersIcons($criteria) {
$users = $criteria['users'];
$nb_display = $criteria['nb_display'];
$width = $criteria['width'];

if($width=='') $width="300";

if($nb_display>count($users) || $nb_display=='') $nb_display=count($users); //display value never bigger than nb users

$display = '';
for($i=0;$i<$nb_display;$i++) {
    $name = $users[$i]['name'];
    $picture = $users[$i]['picture'];
    $url = $users[$i]['url'];
        $display .= '<li class="span4">';
        $display .= '<div class="thumbnail">';
        $display .= '<h3>'.$name.'</h3>';
    $display .= '<a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank" title="'.$name.'">';
    $display .= '<div class="miprofile-pic-cnt" style="background-image:url('.$picture.')" ></div>';
    $display .= '</a>';
    $display .= '<div class="caption">';
    $display .= '<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>';
    $display .= '</div>';
    $display .= '</div>';
    $display .= '</li>';            



}
return $display;
```

}

In this the `<div class="miprofile-pic-cnt" style="background-image:url('.$picture.')" ></div>` is the div I am referring to, and in this the method of background image just displys the image links as `https://graph.facebook.com/7460374244/picture?type=large`, which should be something like `sdsd.jpg`. When I use `img src intead of div, it works fine`

Comment: Does the `div` have a `height` and `width`?  It won't be sized automatically based on the background image.  Also, within the `a` tag, you should be using `span`.

Comment: If you set both values do you see anything (either/or)?  Is the *$picture* variable different between the two when you set both?

Comment: @BlargleMonster yes different in both

Comment: @user Now that I look at it again, why aren't you using an `<img>` tag inside your link?  Why are you making it a `<div>`?